# Pymongo - Sort/Aggregate under a UNSPECIFIC nested value under an _id

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate, pymongo

In case you don't know what I mean by the title I want to be able to sort/aggregate a nested value under an varying object that is not consistant in any situation under a specifc `_id`.

If you still don't know what I mean I will give an example;
We have collection `fruits`

```json
{"_id": 1, "Apple": {"score": 50}, "Banana": {"score" : 40}, "Mango": {"score": 100}, "Watermelon": {"score": 75}}
```

I want to be able to sort this collection into;

```json
{"_id": 1, "Mango": {"score": 100}, "Watermelon": {"score": 75},"Apple": {"score": 50}, "Banana": {"score" : 40}}
```

As you can see this has nothing to do with other `_id`s and the object name is unconsistant (therefore we cannot use dot notation) AND the value is nested in the object

Any answer is greatly appreciated! (preferably pymongo)

NOTE: The objective is to have this `OUTPUT` not rearrange it in the collection itself

Answer (score 0):

This may give you some ideas:

```
       db.collection.aggregate([
      {
       $group: {
         _id: "$_id",
      k: {
    $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
   }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
     "k._id": 0
   }
  },
  {
   $unwind: "$k"
     },
     {
   $project: {
      k: {
       $map: {
         input: {
           "$objectToArray": "$k"
              },
           in: "$$this"
         }
       }
     }
   },
   {
     $unwind: "$k"
   },
   {
    $sort: {
      "k.v.score": -1
     }
   },
   {
     $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      k: {
       $push: "$k"
     }
   }
 }
])
```

Unfortunatelly when I add the conversion to Object at the end it is switching the order to the original:

```
    {
      $addFields: {
       k: {
       $arrayToObject: "$k"
     }
    }
   }
```

which seems to be expected behaviour since JSON do not preserve nested objects order , so you will need to do in python ...

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4C_7-y-zu1Y)

Comment: Great answer! But I'm afraid im looking for something simplier perhaps something more `bulit-in`